# How can I link the view in Spring Boot with my application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have the following problem. I am trying to link my Spring Boot Application to my database via the Entity. However, I am not referencing to a Table, but to a View.
I have the following problem. I am trying to link my Spring Boot Application to my database via the Entity.

My view

```
CREATE VIEW v_location AS
    SELECT DISTINCT a.external_id, a.name, d.loc_x, d.loc_y, d.loc_z 
        FROM group a
            INNER JOIN structure b ON a.id = b.group_id
                INNER JOIN location c ON b.id = c.structure_id
                    INNER JOIN location_point d ON c.id = d.location_id
                        INNER JOIN propertyvalues e on e.id = c.location_type
                            where e.value_string = 'Mittelpunkt';
```

My Entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "`v_location`")
public class LocationEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "external_id")
    private Long externalId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "loc_x")
    private Double locX;

    @Column(name = "loc_y")
    private Double locY;

    @Column(name = "loc_z")
    private Double locZ;

}
```

But now the error is thrown out. On the database level, after running the application, a table was automatically created as an image of the view. In the error description, however, it seems to be that the existing tables want to adjust.
Question: How can I link the view in Spring Boot with my application? Does anyone have a solution for me?

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.5)

14.49.51 INFO  o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger:55 Starting ServiceApplication using Java 11.0.2 on NB000613 with PID 6224 (D:\Repositories\basis-service\target\classes started by  in D:\Repositories\basis-service)
14.49.51 DEBUG o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger:56 Running with Spring Boot v2.4.5, Spring v5.3.6
14.49.51 INFO  o.s.b.SpringApplication:675 No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
14.49.52 INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:128 Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
14.49.52 INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:188 Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 45 ms. Found 6 JPA repository interfaces.
14.49.52 INFO  c.u.j.c.EnableEncryptablePropertiesBeanFactoryPostProcessor:39 Post-processing PropertySource instances
14.49.52 INFO  c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter:56 Converting PropertySource configurationProperties [org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource] to AOP Proxy
14.49.52 INFO  c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter:56 Converting PropertySource servletConfigInitParams [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
14.49.52 INFO  c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter:56 Converting PropertySource servletContextInitParams [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
14.49.52 INFO  c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter:56 Converting PropertySource systemProperties [org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
14.49.52 INFO  c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter:56 Converting PropertySource systemEnvironment [org.springframework.boot.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor$OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource] to EncryptableSystemEnvironmentPropertySourceWrapper
14.49.52 INFO  c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter:56 Converting PropertySource random [org.springframework.boot.env.RandomValuePropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
14.49.52 INFO  c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter:56 Converting PropertySource Config resource 'class path resource [application.properties]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' [org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
14.49.52 INFO  c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter:56 Converting PropertySource devtools [org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
14.49.52 INFO  c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter:56 Converting PropertySource class path resource [springdoc.swagger-ui.config] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
14.49.52 INFO  c.u.j.f.DefaultLazyPropertyFilter:31 Property Filter custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyFilter'. Initializing Default Property Filter
14.49.52 INFO  c.u.j.r.DefaultLazyPropertyResolver:35 Property Resolver custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyResolver'. Initializing Default Property Resolver
14.49.52 INFO  c.u.j.d.DefaultLazyPropertyDetector:35 Property Detector custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyDetector'. Initializing Default Property Detector
14.49.52 INFO  o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer:108 Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
14.49.52 INFO  o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog:173 Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
14.49.52 INFO  o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog:173 Starting service [Tomcat]
14.49.52 INFO  o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog:173 Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
14.49.52 INFO  o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog:173 Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
14.49.52 INFO  o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext:289 Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 671 ms
14.49.52 DEBUG o.s.w.f.GenericFilterBean:242 Filter 'CORSFilter' configured for use
14.49.52 INFO  o.h.j.i.u.LogHelper:31 HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
14.49.52 INFO  c.z.h.HikariDataSource:110 HikariPool-12 - Starting...
14.49.52 INFO  c.z.h.HikariDataSource:123 HikariPool-12 - Start completed.
14.49.52 INFO  o.h.d.Dialect:175 HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table structure 
       add constraint FKtmaql4i7y6f4sgngykvn3j0hp 
       foreign key (group_id) 
       references group
14.49.52 WARN  o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl:27 GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    alter table structure 
       add constraint FKtmaql4i7y6f4sgngykvn3j0hp 
       foreign key (group_id) 
       references group" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table structure 
       add constraint FKtmaql4i7y6f4sgngykvn3j0hp 
       foreign key (group_id) 
       references group" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
    at de.basisServiceApplication.main(ServiceApplication.java:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: there is no primary key for referenced table "structure_group"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:322)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:279)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Are you using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`? if so, can you disable it?

Comment: i am using spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update should i change this?

Comment: Yes. Why have you kept it at `update`? May be use `validate`? Can you instead use SQL scripts outside of the application or use something like Flyway or Liquibase?